# Problem with downloading file in DRF+Angular

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am doing project on DRF+Angular. Currently on localhost I can download file with action:

```
    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
    def download(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        file_handle = instance.file.open()
        response = FileResponse(file_handle.read(), content_type='application/file')
        response['Content-Length'] = instance.file.size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{instance.file.name}"'    
        file_handle.close()
        return response
```

It works on localhost, but when front-end tries to get the same file under the same url on server - I get a redirection to a DRF template with `HTTP 401 Unauthorized`. But I have already entered my credentials. What is going wrong?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with frontend cross origin
you can read more about it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Also at django you can use [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to solve it 
I can't be sure as you didn't provide full details of your webserver configurations

Check also response headers
do you add Accept with file type ??

```
'Content-Description: File Transfer'
'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"'
'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)
'Pragma: public'
'Cache-Control: must-revalidate'
'Expires: 0'
'Accept: <MIME_type>/*'
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)

Comment: Sorry, just read your message. CORS is already used, as I know - there is no any other problem with Django-Angular communication, except this file downloading. And It works if I provide credentials directly into DRF api admin - then I can download the file. Looks like some Headers problem.

Comment: Can you check these response headers